# Alert message on duplicate entry

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have been working in codeigniter i have applied unique key for email address .So when i enter duplicate email address it displays Error Number: 1062

Duplicate entry 'moses@gmail.com' for key 'email_address' So i want that to be display in alert pls help me to solve the issue.

```
function create_member()
    {

        $new_member_insert_data = array(
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'email_address' => $this->input->post('email_address'),         
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => md5($this->input->post('password'))                       
        );

        $insert = $this->db->insert('membership', $new_member_insert_data);
        if ($this->db->_error_number() == 1062)
                {
                echo "Duplicate value";
                }
        return $insert;
    }
```

Comment: and how this `create_member` is getting called?

Comment: it is called from controller

Comment: is it an ajax. i mean the action in controller?

Comment: So since you can pass the value to the corresponding view you are rendering in the action and there you can show the alert

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// Controller "membership"

function register() {

    if($this->input->post()){

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_address', 'Email', 'trim|required|xss_clean|is_unique[membership.email_address]');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){

            $this->load->model('membership_model');
            $this->membership_model->create_member();

        }

    }

}


// Model "membership_model"

function create_member() {

        $new_member_insert_data = array(
            'first_name' => $this->input->post('first_name'),
            'last_name' => $this->input->post('last_name'),
            'email_address' => $this->input->post('email_address'),         
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'password' => md5($this->input->post('password'))                       
        );

        if ($this->db->insert('membership', $new_member_insert_data)) {
            return TRUE;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `flashdata` from `session` class.

you can set:

```
if ($this->db->_error_number() == 1062)
{
$this->session->set_flashdata('duplicate_email', 'Duplicate value');
redirect('your_previous_page');
}
```

and in the "view" page get the `duplicate_email` value and show the error message:

```
$err = $this->session->flashdata('duplicate_email');

echo $err;
```

[Documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html)